# Updating Razor LabelFor() from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Razor. I have an AJAX function that obtains the city and state when you type in the zip code. I then update a list box with city/cities and update a LabelFor with the State as shown in image:

[image: image1]

The JSON function:

[image: image2]

Razor Code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()), "Select City", new { @class = "drop-down-list", id = "city_drop_down_id", style = "font-size:100%;" })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, new { id="state_label_id", style = "font-size:100%; font-weight:normal; color:black;" })
```

The controls are successfully updated by the Javascript once the Ajax function retrieves the data. 
Now if I click Next button, a form post is made and I should be getting the values in the controls into my Controller. The issue is, that I'm getting the City from the drop down but not the State:

[image: image3]

The full image is not clear, so here is a close up:

[image: image4]

I used DisplayFor instead of LabelFor and it still won't work. I even used .html() in the javascript, instead of .text() but still no luck:

```
$("#state_label_id").html(this.State);
```

(Please ignore user name, password, email address as I'm not passing any values to those, so the null is expected)

Comment: You need serialize label text for sending to server?

Comment: You must use`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State, "Value");` for send that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @AmirNorouzpour, that worked. This is what I did:

```
Razor Code:
-----------
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.State, new { id = "state_label_id_hidden" }) 

JQuery:
------
$("#state_label_id_hidden").val(this.State);
```